# Tailwindcss - How to order columns vertically?

Tags: tailwind-css

With tailwind css, how can I order columns vertically?

Please see https://play.tailwindcss.com/kPS1eigovs

I thought grid-flow-col would have worked, but output not as expected.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define row count as well besides column count.

```
<div class="grid grid-rows-4 grid-cols-2 gap-4 grid-flow-col">
```

Check working [example](https://play.tailwindcss.com/WnVrvb4S2U).